# Problems on editing json file (Error: Parse error on line 1:...Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL'

Tags: json

I am not a programmer, but a software translator, and I received a job with some JSON files, and have to edit them. Unfortunately, when I use Passollo from SDL Trados, and any other JSON editing program (http://jsoneditoronline.org/), I receive the error message below:

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
var start = [
    {
^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

The file below runs smoothly, but when I try to edit them, the syntax of them have an error, and the parsers detects them.

```
var start = [
    {
        type:   "top_img",
        child:  [
            {STRING
                id:"001",
                title:"POD Deck Lite-B1 Service Manual Rev0.0",
                href:"../frame_images/A021POD2-COVER-0001.gif"
            }
        ]
    },{
        type:   "menu",
        child:  [
            {
                id:"001",
                title:"Technology",
                description:"Technology"
            },{
                id:"002",
                title:"Service",
                description:"Service"
            },{
                id:"003",
                title:"Appendix",
                description:"Appendix"
            }
        ]
    },{
        type:   "reference",
        child:  [
            {
                id:"001",
                title:"How to use",
                src:"how to use",
                href:"../frame_htmls/how to use.html"
            },{
                id:"002",
                title:"Read me",
                src:"readme",
                href:"../frame_htmls/readme.html"
            },{
                id:"003",
                title:"Site map",
                src:"sitemap",
                href:"../frame_htmls/sitemap.html"
            },{
                id:"004",
                title:"History",
                src:"history",
                href:"../frame_htmls/history.xls"
            }
        ]
    },{
        type:   "header",
        child:  [
            {
                id:"001",
                title:"Home",
                href:"../esm.htm"
            },{
                id:"002",
                title:"Site map",
                href:"../frame_htmls/sitemap.html"
            }
        ]
    }

];
```

Can someone help me with the solution for this error message, or edit 5 files according to json parser rules, in order to allow me to edit them to my target language?

Comment: Use a "linter" to help. https://jsonlint.com/ JSON has to be accurate down to the `,`. If you're missing a single thing it fails. All that stuff has to be put in double quotes `"`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a unnecessary `STRING` before id.

Make sure all the property names are enclosed in quotes. This should work.

```
[
   {
      "type":"top_img",
      "child":[
         {
            "id":"001",
            "title":"POD Deck Lite-B1 Service Manual Rev0.0",
            "href":"../frame_images/A021POD2-COVER-0001.gif"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "type":"menu",
      "child":[
         {
            "id":"001",
            "title":"Technology",
            "description":"Technology"
         },
         {
            "id":"002",
            "title":"Service",
            "description":"Service"
         },
         {
            "id":"003",
            "title":"Appendix",
            "description":"Appendix"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "type":"reference",
      "child":[
         {
            "id":"001",
            "title":"How to use",
            "src":"how to use",
            "href":"../frame_htmls/how to use.html"
         },
         {
            "id":"002",
            "title":"Read me",
            "src":"readme",
            "href":"../frame_htmls/readme.html"
         },
         {
            "id":"003",
            "title":"Site map",
            "src":"sitemap",
            "href":"../frame_htmls/sitemap.html"
         },
         {
            "id":"004",
            "title":"History",
            "src":"history",
            "href":"../frame_htmls/history.xls"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "type":"header",
      "child":[
         {
            "id":"001",
            "title":"Home",
            "href":"../esm.htm"
         },
         {
            "id":"002",
            "title":"Site map",
            "href":"../frame_htmls/sitemap.html"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: Hi Suresh, thanks for your help, but the changes made as below don't worked. I receive the same error message from the json editor. See the changes made. I hope to hear from you soon. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

```
function search(source) {
    //console.log("My Result: "+source);
    $.ajax({
        url: "index.ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        data: { action:"search", source:source, form:$("form#main").serialize() },
        complete: function(data) {
            var d = JSON.stringify(data);

            //table
            $('#table_data').html(d.table);
            $("input[name='count']").val(d.count);
            $("#time").html(d.time);
            console.log("My Result: "+ d);

            //pagination
            from = Number($("input[name='start']").val());
            to = (Number(data.count) > (Number($("input[name='limit']").val())+from)) ? Number($("input[name='limit']").val())+from : data.count;
            if(data.count == 0) {
                $('#page_info').html('<p>No results found.</p>');
                $('#next').hide();
            } else {
                $('#page_info').html('<p>Showing '+(from+1)+' to '+to+' of '+data.count+'  records in total.</p>');
                $('#next').show();
            }

        },
        error: function(data) {
            $('#table_data').html('<tr><td colspan="20">Results error. Please contact admin.</td><tr>');
            $("#page_info").html("<p>Load error.</p>");
        }
        /*        error:function(x,e) {
         if (x.status==0) {
         alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
         } else if(x.status==404) {
         alert('Requested URL not found.');
         } else if(x.status==500) {
         alert('Internel Server Error.');
         } else if(e=='parsererror') {
         alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.');
         } else if(e=='timeout'){
         alert('Request Time out.');
         } else {
         alert('Unknown Error.\n'+x.responseText);
         }
         }*/
    });
}
```

Comment: I also get the above error in my code above: Error: Parse error on line 1:
function search(sour
^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'